# Facebook places API: is it possible to do a "near by" query?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to get places by latitude/longitude and radius using the Graph API (or by address/zip)? I don't see it anywhere in the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following format for the search URL will return a list of places near a location:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=<lat>,<lon>&distance=1000&access_token=<token>
```

I'm not sure on the units of the "distance" parameter.

Comment: According to a forum post (http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82760), Facebook Places uses "meter" as the unit of distance.  I did not found any in their documentation.  I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Their documentation also doesn't state what is the maximum allowed distance (radius). Very poor documentation if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the facebook API, but if you can pull the lat/long of two places, you can calculate their distance quite easily. Here it is in JavaScript, but it's portable to about any language:

```
var R = 6371; // km .. use 3963 for miles
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c; // km
```

Hopefully this helps you with your endeavor.

Comment: Thank you but I don't know which places are around my coordinate.